# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using "SHC" to convert script to binary file

Tags: shell, binary

What are the advantages / disadvantages of converting a shell script into a binary file?

I have done that and when I run the binary file on another linux it doesn't run.

it gives this error
`version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./test.sh.x)`

on another server it gives this `./test.sh.x: Invalid argument.`

The script only does a `echo "hello"`

Comment: `What are the advantages / disadvantages of converting a shell script into a binary file?` -- Too many opinion based questions today.

Comment: One major disadvantage is that the binary often doesn't run when you move it to another machine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only 'advantage' is obfuscation, the disadvantages numerous as the examples in your question show.

If you're using it to hide secrets (passwords) they are easy to extract anyway.